# How is differentiation under integration being applied here?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Suppose $$\frac{\partial p(x_0)}{\partial x_0}=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_0}(1,x_0)=\exp \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_0}(s,\phi(s,x_0))ds$$

Then it is written in my textbook that:

$$p''(x_0)=p'(x_0)\left(\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_0 \partial x_0}(s,\phi(s,x_0)).\exp\left(\int_{0}^{s}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_0}(u,\phi(u,x_0))du\right)ds\right)$$

I'm not sure how they got the $\exp\left(\int_{0}^{s}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_0}(u,\phi(u,x_0))du\right)$ term.

Shouldn't it just be

$$p''(x_0)=p'(x_0)\left(\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_0 \partial x_0}(s,\phi(s,x_0))ds\right)$$ using differentiation under integration sign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the $\exp$ part is supposed to be
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_0}(s, x_0)
=\exp\left(\int_0^s \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_0}(u, \phi(u, x_0)) d u\right)
$$
but I don't know if the equality is true. We need to know more about $\phi$.

Using this equality we get

$$
\frac{d}{d x_0}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_0}(s, \phi(s, x_0)) d s\right)
=
\int_0^1 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x_0}(s, \phi(s, x_0))
 \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_0}(s, x_0)d s
$$

Comment: Yes, that equality is true. After that?

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: It is only the chain rule applied to the composition $x_0 \mapsto \phi(s, x_0)\mapsto \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_0}(s, \phi(s, x_0))$.